# Flutter: Using an array of Stateful Widgets inside a Stateful Widget causes a 'A RenderFlex overflow'

Tags: dart, flutter

Im learning Flutter and I came across this strange behaviour while building a simple app. I've created a custom Stateful Widget and I simply can't use it inside another Stateful Widget. Is it the expected behaviour or I'm missing something here?

The errors are:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(375.0,
>       812.0), devicePixelRatio: 3.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 34.0),
>       viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false)):
>       The method '_debugTypesAreRight' was called on null.
>       Receiver: null
>       Tried calling: _debugTypesAreRight(Instance of 'TextCard')

and

> Another exception was thrown: The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild
>   layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child:

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stateful Widget 02',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Testing nested Stateful Widgets'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextCard(),
            new TextCard()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class TextCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    _TextCardState createState() => new _TextCardState();
  }
}

class _TextCardState extends State<TextCard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
        child: new Text('12312')
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are overriding `createState()` in `TextCard` the wrong way.

**Replace:**

```
createState() {
    _TextCardState createState() => new _TextCardState();
  }
```

**With:**

```
@override
_TextCardState createState(){
    return new _TextCardState();
  }
```